# why does the memcmp function in c use cast into unsigned char instead of just char?

Tags: c++, c

```
int memcmp(const void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n);
```

most of the implementations of memcmp function in c cast the arguments s1 and s2 into unsigned char.
I am aware the the two arguments are casted to char so that memcmp compare 1 byte at a time, but why use unsigned char instead of just char ?

I tried to understand the function by reading its source code but I couldn't understand that specific part.

Comment: Back in the ancient times when dinosaurs roamed the Earth, different operating systems declared the library functions is slightly different ways. There is no particular reason to use one vs. the other vs. the third possibility. That's simply the way it is, no special meaning to it.

Comment: Because that is what the standard specifies (here ISO-C99): "The sign of a nonzero value returned by the comparison functions `memcmp`, `strcmp`, and `strncmp` is determined by the sign of the difference between the values of the first pair of characters (both interpreted as `unsigned char`) that differ in the objects being compared."

Comment: Usually, when you compare bytes or bits, you want to use an `unsigned` type. The only ancient reason I can imagine: an OS with sign+magnitude numbers might have 2 different `0` (e.g. `+0` and `-0`), comparing `+0 == -0` will lead to `true`, even when the bits are different.

Comment: Apart from being mandated by the standard, `unsigned char` is more portable (i.e., consistent across supported platforms). C permits 3 different representations for signed integers (2's complement, 1s' complement, sign and magnitude). Unsigned integers have just one.

Comment: Also `char`, `unsigned char` and `signed char` are 3 distinct types.  `char` may be signed or unsigned depending on the implementation.  So a library writer writing portable code should probably avoid `char` due to subtle differences (pointed out above) between signed and unsigned.

Comment: @njuffa, that sounds like it could be made into an answer.

Comment: @YounessAsserare, there is nothing inherently wrong with reading source code for various implementations of standard library functions, but if what you want to understand is the *meaning* of the function then it is the function's *documentation* that you should focus on.  Note also that C standard libraries tend not to be good sources of example C code to assist in learning C.  They are often more complex than a typical C student wants for examples, and they tend to take liberties that are justified for them, but not for you.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, part of an assignment i have to do is to remake a number of libc functions such as memcmp, I made it using plain char which seems fine at first until i tested it with more test cases. then, i read some of the solutions my classmates did and saw that they used unsigned char. they tried explaining it but I never really understood why.

Comment: Again, @YounessAsserare, your best resource, *especially* for writing a work-alike, is documentation.  That's what details what the function is supposed to do.  The language specification itself is the primary and best source for such docs, but there are other good ones.  As far as why your attempt did not pass all its test cases, asking that specifically, with a [mre], would make for a better SO question.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to write these comments ! can you link  me a documentation website that would help me.

Comment: @YounessAsserare The usual suggestion at this point would be [cppreference.com](https://cppreference.com).

Answer (score 3):

When you look at a code page table for strcmp, or just plain bytes for memcmp, you would expect 0x80-0xff to compare *higher* than 0x00-0x7f, right?

This only works if the comparison is done *unsigned*. Otherwise, 0x80-0xff would (on two's-complement architectures) be *negative*, i.e. *lower* than 0x00-0x7f.

The signedness of plain `char` is implementation-defined. So in order to give the expected results on *all* platforms, the comparison cannot be done in plain `char` -- you need to work in `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule of thumb when dealing with raw binary data is to always use unsigned types. This is mostly because various forms of bitwise operations come with various forms of poorly-defined behavior when handed signed or negative operands.

`char` is the only type in C that can be either signed or unsigned depending on the compiler, so it is also a problematic type for that reason alone. A good rule of thumb (and also a MISRA C rule) is to never use `char` for any other purpose than string handling. Use `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` when dealing with raw binary.

For comparisons alone, the signedness is unlikely to matter though. But you can turn the question the other way around, why would we use a signed type to compare raw binary data? There is no known sign in the data. We only end up with the sign bit set if the conversion misinterprets the raw binary as a negative integer value. And that's neither useful nor sensible behavior, so why even allow it even if it is harmless?

For the specific case of `memcmp`, there's also a special rule for how to calculate the result, C17 7.24.4:

> The sign of a nonzero value returned by the comparison functions `memcmp`, `strcmp`, and `strncmp` is determined by the sign of the difference between the values of the first
> pair of characters (both interpreted as `unsigned char`) that differ in the objects being
> compared.

So no matter how we implement `memcmp`, the returned result in case of differences must be calculated using arithmetic on `unsigned char`.

As for how most library-quality `memcmp` are actually implemented, they are only likely to use `unsigned char` for the parts dealing with misaligned offsets of the data. The raw comparisons on aligned data is likely done with a large integer type suitable for the specific CPU, such as `uint32_t` or `uint64_t`.